# Integrating an API that uses SSL to connect machines

Tags: c#, ssl

I want to integrate an API that will allow my application to send requests to a web server. Unfortunately, this API is not well documented, and I have not gotten a reply from the person who supports the web service that released the API. The instructions on how to integrate the API are the following:

> All API calls connect to the standard SSL port, and must begin with
>   https://www.websitename.com/api.php?username=username&password=password&,
>   followed by the list of parameters expressed as `parametername=value&`

I am new to C# development. Can you interpret this set of instructions and tell me how I'd go about integrating this API? I mainly am confused about connecting to the SSL port.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it's just an HTTP request to that particular URL. You want to use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class, and possibly call the `DownloadString` method, depending on what the response contains.

Comment: Thanks. I did not use DownloadString. I am sending data to a webclient, so I ended up using the WebClient.UploadString method.

Answer (score 0):

The standard SSL port is `443`, but if you're using a library that parses URLs correctly, it will connect to that port automatically if it sees `https://` at the beginning. You can use a custom port by providing it after the hostname (separated by a `:`), such as `https://websitename.com:8443/`, if you had an SSL service running on port `8443` instead of `443`.